# [Forge 1.8.9]: Including dependencies in JAR

Tags: gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge, snakeyaml

I've been making a Forge mod for Minecraft 1.8.9 with the Forge MDK. So far my mod has 1 dependency, which is SnakeYAML. I added this line: `compile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.30'` to my `build.gradle` file, so that I have SnakeYAML during development, but it doesn't get included when I build the JAR. Is there any way to include SnakeYAML in my JAR as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a fat Jar. In summary, a fat Jar contains all of the dependency classes and resources in a single output Jar. I assume you're using Gradle as this is a Forge project.

Add the [Shadow plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/)

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
  id 'java'
}
```

Then configure your dependencies to shadow in SnakeYAML:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.30'
  ...
  shadow 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.30'
}
```

Finally, use the ShadowJar task added under 'Shadow' to build your fat Jar. You may need to change the version of Shadow for the gradle version you're using. Refer to the [documentation](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) for any configuration you may wish to add.

Comment: The MDK for 1.8.9 was using Gradle 2.13, so I had to use Shadow v1.2.4, and it successfully built the Fat JAR. But for some reason, it's causing a new error when I run the Fat JAR in Minecraft. Here's the log: https://pastebin.com/YaDQfQqq. Any ideas?

Comment: See point number 15 from [this post](https://forums.minecraftforge.net/topic/61757-common-issues-and-recommendations/#comment-289566). If it works when you `runClient` but not when you try and use the mod, this is likely the issue.

Comment: But my mod works if I just export it as a normal JAR and run it with SnakeYAML. It only starts crashing when it's as a Fat JAR.